# Can ordinal data be transformed to nominal data?

Tags: categorical-data, spss, kruskal-wallis-test

I have five variables all in the ordinal form. The measurement goes like this- 5- Strongly agree, 4- Agree, 3- Neither agree nor disagree, 2- Disagree, and 1- Strongly disagree.

Now, out of the five variables, I would like to use one as the dependent variable and the other four as the independent variables for a Kruskall Wallis-H test.

I know that the Kruskall Wallis test can employ an ordinal variable as the dependent variable. However,the independent variable needs to be a categorical/nominal variable (as far as I know, please feel free to correct me if I am wrong).

Therefore, can I transform the other 4 ordinal variables into nominal variables so that I can use them as independent variables for the Kruskall Wallis test?

If so, what would be the the new categories? Also, it would be great if someone could share a good research article on transforming ordinal into nominal variables. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why Kruskal-Wallis and not a test on rank correlation?

Comment: That's a good question but it's because of two reasons- I want to treat one of the ordinal variables as the dependent variable and show that the other independent variables are dependent on it.  Secondly, Kruskall Wallis test will show that there is a statistically significant difference between the groups unlike rank correlation which only shows that there is a significant correlation between the factors. I want to show that being in one group is better than being on another.

Comment: The first argument does not count as the same reasoning works for a test on monotonicity. Regarding the second: If you really want to ignore the order in the "covariate" levels, then go for KW test.